# NotifyDataSetChanged at back button doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, android-adapter, back-button

I have an app which has two `Intents`. First display some objects, the second one favourite objects which are objects from the first `Intent` but marked as 'favourite'. When I am at the second `Intent` - favourite, I want to unmarked object to become 'regular' object and then when I click `back button` the list of objects refreshed and disply a enable button 'add to favourite'. But it doesn't work:

Favourite `intent`:

```
public class FavWashActivity extends Activity{

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    private List<WashLocation> washLocations;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favorite_wash);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fav_recycler_view);
        DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        washLocations = dataBaseHelper.getFavouriteWashLocation();
        mAdapter = new MyAdapterFavWash(washLocations, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(null, this, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And the `adapter` which needs to be refreshed:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<WashLocation> washLocations;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
    private Map<String, Integer> queueToWash;

    public MyAdapter(List<WashLocation> washLocations, Context context, Map<String, Integer> queueToWash) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.washLocations = washLocations;
        dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        this.queueToWash = queueToWash;
    }
```

Comment: you need to refresh your list in `onResume` in first `Activity` instead of `onBackPressed`

Comment: refreshing data in onResume is not a good way, because if user press home and back to your activity you refresh list that is redundant, better way is `onActivityResult` and if user change any item in second activity you refresh list, else don't refresh data.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
           @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                super.onBackPressed();
                washLocations.remove(1);
                //need to change in arraylist than only you can notify your adapter.
               //add some data in array list or remove data.than try to notify it.
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

hope this help you..if need need any help than you can ask for it.

Comment: But this solution will always remove first element. What about when user would remove in the middle?

Comment: @bielas i just gave example that u need to change something in ur arraylist than only u can notify ur adapter...if u want to remove from middle than u need to put ur logic for that...actually why u want to refresh ur list in onResume()?

Comment: If u click back button than that activity will be finish and when u again come back to this activity it will automatically refresh..

Comment: No it isn't. When I click the back button the list in the first activity doesn't refresh

Comment: Than use startActivityForResult for starting Second activity from first when u press backpress u can take arraylist back to first activity update ur arraylist in onActivityResult and notify ur array list...

Comment: Check this....   https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example